# Create ping monitor with proxy

Tags: ssh, networking, monitoring, proxy

There are 3 sites. One local and two remote.

Local  machines can initiate a connection to any site. Sites can initiate a connection between themselves. Remote sites, however, can't initiate a connection to local.

I'm looking for a simple ping monitoring that could be deployed locally, and ping a server in SiteA through SiteB, and report back to local.

I have looked at nagios but it seems like wether I use ssh or nrpe (the nagios agent), it needs a bunch of setup on the server that would act as proxy. It also seems to have quite a learning curve as once I've got the command for the check I want, I couldn't figure out how to add it to the webgui.

Is there an free/opensource tool that easily allows setting something like this up, with preferably the following options:

- minimal installation on the remote servers (preferably via SSH)
- Alert
- Schedual time so between specific hours, it wouldn't do anything.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: `zabbix` is okay as a monitoring solution. However that also requires setting up an agent, and the web UI is rather complex.

Comment: I am not certain I understand the question or desired results. You said "installed locally"--What is wrong with the `ping` command that is already part of the base system? Scheduling can be done with cron jobs (or systemd timers, if your system uses systemd, or other methods depending on OS). Not certain what you mean by "report back to local". Or why you need a proxy in any case, since all the tools you need are already part of almost any networking-aware OS. Please edit your question to clarify and give specifics.